# How to make friends react.js app, nginx and docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, nginx-config

React app is a client, so it has some endpoint to connect to (no matter, axios http or websocket)

Typically, backend-like clients (various modular-server microservices) obtains it from ENV, that is set up during container build process, and declared in docker-compose.yml file. Everything in a build process is required to launch app, and final step is a run command.

React Frontend also needs build procedure, but that differs in a sense that you actually not running "bundle.js" upon build completion, and dont need all the rest after build. Actually I build on host, and in docker-compose.yml, I say: "nginx image", and "mount external config and static files as a volumes". But that way I cannot use endpoint, and nginx proxy to backend api is not working.

Should I write Dockerfile for building frontend, and what ideas on how to integrate it to nginx resulting image? (for building I need node image, but for running I need nginx, while deleting sources and packages..

---

Trying to reword it in short terms

- In dev mode backend:someport is running locally and frontend webserver:80 is proxyfying api requests to localhost:someport
- If you put backend in container nothing would change
- If you put webserver in container localhost:someport will stop working, because there is no is no backend:someport running inside that container, obviously...
- Production front needs build procedure, which involves tons of temp files

Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Month later I've retirned here, and could share found solution. Best results were achieved via two-pass build procedure. Here is a simple dockerfile, illistrating this approach:

```
#dont use alpine if you need gyp (web3, sha3 and friends..)
FROM node:current as builder
WORKDIR /frontend

# install packages
COPY ./.yarnrc ./
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN yarn install

# build front
COPY ./.babelrc ./
COPY ./webpack.config.js ./
COPY ./pub ./pub
COPY ./src ./src
RUN yarn build

# copy result static to nginx
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=builder /frontend/dist/ /data/www/
COPY ./nginx /etc/nginx
```

---

PROS:

- Everything (static, configs) is bundled inside an image
- No need for any volumes (logs are streamed to syslog)
- Tiny image size (around 20 megs)
- Extremely easy to deploy - just upload image and here you go
- No need to have node.js and friends installed on dev machine

CONS:

- Long rebuild time if React sources were changed
- Sometimes volumes may be convenient